# how to use "keep in dictionary" in a function using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to extract part of them using robot framework. I saw that the keyword "keep in dictionary" is exactly what I need, but I'm not able to use it.

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Keep%20In%20Dictionary

```
$users=  [
   {
     'name': 'Maria'
     'age': 23,
     'gender': 'Female'
   },{
     'name': 'Martha'
     'age': 33,
     'gender': 'Female'
   },{
     'name': 'John'
     'age': 41,
     'gender': 'Male'
   }
]
```

what I need now is get name and age and discard the gender. For this I want to create my own keyword because I'm going to use it using different keys in every part of my application. My try:

```
Get data from users
   [Arguments]  @{keys}
   @{userData}  Copy list  ${users}
   :FOR    ${user}    IN    @{users}
   \       Keep in Dictionary  ${user}  ${keys}
[Return]  ${userData}
```

it doesnt work, because ${keys} is a list and is not the parameter that the function is expected.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it, thanks to the answer I was given here

[Convert a list into a list of parameters using robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910466/convert-a-list-into-a-list-of-parameters-using-robot-framework)

```
Get data from users
   [Arguments]  @{keys}
   @{userData}  Copy list  ${users}
   :FOR    ${user}    IN    @{users}
   \       Keep in Dictionary  ${user}  @{keys}
   [Return]  ${userData}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Remove From Dictionary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Remove%20From%20Dictionary) instead of `Keep In Dictionary`. Below is the robot script:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    ${keysToRemove}  Create List  gender
    ${desiredList}   Remove Data From Users    ${users}    ${keysToRemove}


*** Keywords ***
Remove Data From Users
    [Arguments]     ${users}    ${keysToRemove}

    ${userData}      Create List  

    ${length}   Get Length  ${users}

    FOR  ${INDEX}  IN RANGE  ${length}        
        ${modifiedDictionary}   Remove Keys From Dictionary  ${users[${INDEX}]}  ${keysToRemove}
        Append To List  ${userData}  ${modifiedDictionary}
    END

    [Return]    ${userData}


Remove Keys From Dictionary
    [Arguments]     ${dictionary}     ${keysToRemove}

    ${length}     Get Length  ${keysToRemove} 

    FOR     ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    ${length}
        Remove From Dictionary  ${dictionary}     ${keysToRemove[${INDEX}]}
    END

    [Return]    ${dictionary}
```

The implementation has 2 keywords `Remove Data From Users` and `Remove Keys From Dictionary`.

`Remove Data From Users` takes 2 arguments `users` and `keysToRemove`. `users` is a list of user dictionaries and `keyToRemove` is a list of the keys that you want removed from `users`

`Remove Keys From Dictionary` takes 2 arguments `dictionary` and `keysToRemove`. `dictionary` is the individual user details passed as a dictionary and `keysToRemove` is the list of keys to be removed. This is only a helper function for the `Remove Data From Users` keyword.

`${desiredList}` will contain the same user list with the gender removed from the original list.

The above should help you achieve what you intend, but there could be other ways to approach your problem as well.

> Note: The helper keyword is needed due to a drawback of Robot Framework since it does not support nested for loops. You could also define the `Remove Data From Users` as a pure python keyword and get rid of the second helper keyword.

Comment: thanks, but this is not useful for me, remove instead of keep is a dirty solution for me, and makes the code unreadable, if I need to loop I will loop to copy. 

Apart of this, not necesary to use positional arguments in the loop, you can loop as :FOR    ${key}   IN   ${keysToRemove}

Comment: Well, this was one way I could think of. It is totally up to you to take or leave it. Also, I do understand that iterating over a list element is possible in Python, I was only using one of the alternatives.