# Convert a list into a list of parameters using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm using robot framework and I want to use a keyword that acepts a variable number of parameters

this is the common use of this keyworkd

```
keyWord to use  var1  var2 var3
```

Now I want to use it from my own keyword because it will be common in my project, and I want to avoid repeat the loop in every file. This is what I tried

```
Get data from users  var1  var2  var3

Get data from users
  [Arguments]  @{keys}
  :FOR    ${user}    IN    @{users}
  \       keyWord to use  ${keys}
  [Return]  ${userData}
```

But this is not working because ${keys} is a list.

Is it anyway to convert this list:

```
${keys}   ['var1','var2','var3']
```

into this positional arguments:

```
var1  var2  var3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it anyway to convert this list: ... into this positional arguments:

Yes, pass it as an argument, with the `@` prefix - that will expand it, and every member will be an argument to the called keyword:

```
  \       keyWord to use  @{keys}
```

Comment: thanks, I was crazy with this. Please update your answer, you wrote ${keys} instead of @{keys}

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, I did not put it correctly in the one place I was explaining it should be put :)

Answer (score 2):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Keyword with args
Some Keyword    a    b    c

*** Keywords ***
Some Keyword
    [Arguments]     @{args}
    Another keyword with args    @{args}

Another keyword with args
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    : FOR    ${arg}    IN    @{args}
    \    Log To Console    Another keyword prints: ${arg}
```

Outputs:

```
Another keyword prints: a
Another keyword prints: b
Another keyword prints: c
```